# Nesting an svg symbol with scaling and translation relative to parent

Tags: svg, nested, scale, translate

I want to nest a set of svg pentagons inside each other, to get a result like this:

[image: nested pentagons]

I can do this by manually setting the `translate` and `scale` values relative to the outer svg.

```
<svg class="defs-only"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="pentagon">
    <polygon
points="
190.2113,0
0,138.1966
72.6542,361.8034
307.7684,361.8034
380.4226,138.1966
"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg id="1" style="fill:#666" viewBox="0 0 380 362" width="380" height="362">
  <use xlink:href="#pentagon"/>

  <svg id="2" style="fill:#777" viewBox="0 0 380 362" width="380" height="362">
    <use xlink:href="#pentagon" transform="translate(72.5 138) scale(0.618 0.618)"/>

    <svg id="3" style="fill:#888" viewBox="0 0 380 362" width="380" height="362">
      <use xlink:href="#pentagon" transform="translate(118 225) scale(0.381924 0.381924)"/>
    </svg>  
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Is there a way that I can use the same `translate` and `scale` values in each nested layer, and have those values relative to the immediate parent? Will this mean using a percentage value for `translate`, and is this possible?

Heres a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6v4houc/).

Context: eventually, I want the user to be able to drag the shapes around, with each moving the same way relative to its parent, in order to be able to create images like this:

[image]

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Thinkingarena)

---

EDIT: Here's the [final version of the game](http://keplar.fr/puzzles/0001/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Like so:

```html
<svg class="defs-only"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="pentagon">
    <polygon
points="
190.2113,0
0,138.1966
72.6542,361.8034
307.7684,361.8034
380.4226,138.1966
"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 380 362" width="380" height="362">

    <g id="pent2and3">
        <use xlink:href="#pentagon" style="fill:#777"/>
        <use xlink:href="#pentagon" style="fill:#888" transform="translate(72.5 138) scale(0.618 0.618)"/>
    </g>

    <g id="pent1">
        <use xlink:href="#pentagon" style="fill:#666"/>
        <use xlink:href="#pent2and3" transform="translate(72.5 138) scale(0.618 0.618)"/>
    </g>

</svg>
```